# Stuck on proving convergence of infinite series over the quotient of two values of a convergent sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

in preparation for my real calculus exam, I found an exercise problem in my text book which I can't seem to solve. Given is a sequence $(a_n)$, which is positive, monotone and has an upper bound. The task is to proof, that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} - 1\right)$$
converges, but I don't seem to make any progress.

Obviously, $(a_n)$ converges. I thought about using Cauchy's convergence test, but I didn't make much progress with that because I don't see a way to find a $n_0(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$.

Another approach I thought of would be to directly prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} - 1\right)$$ exists. This sequence of partial sums if monotone, because $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ is positive, so it would be sufficient to find an upper bound. Because I couldn't think of a reasonable one I thought about a proof by contradiction, assuming that $$\forall b \in \mathbb{R} \exists n\in\mathbb{N} : \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}-1\right) > b$$
This would imply that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\right) > b + n$$ but I don't see a way to find a contradiction from there.

As you can tell, I'm really stuck on that problem and would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: This is true if $a_k$ is nondecreasing.  In that case you have $a_k\nearrow r$ for some $r$ that satisfies $0<r<\infty$ and you can find bounds of the form $0\leq \frac{a_{k+1} - a_k}{a_k} \leq ...$.

Comment: A counter-example holds when $a_k$ is decreasing, such as $a_k =\frac{1}{k!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a_k$ is non-decreasing and bounded from above by $M$.

Let $\epsilon_k = \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} - 1 \ge 0$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^p \epsilon_k \le \prod_{k=1}^p (1+\epsilon_k) - 1
= \prod_{k=1}^p \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} - 1 = \frac{a_{p+1}}{a_1} - 1 \le \frac{M}{a_1} - 1 < \infty $$
So the partial sums of $\epsilon_k$ is bounded from above. Since $\epsilon_k$ is non-negative, the partial sums is monotonic increasing. As a result, the partial sums converges as a sequence. This is equivalent to the convergence of the sum/series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \epsilon_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}-1\right)$$